# Calculate the curve integral with given cylinder equation and planes

Tags: calculus, integration

For the vector field $a = [- 2x-y, z, 2z]^T$  and the area $F$ on the cylinder $x^2 + z^2 = 4$, which is above the ground plane $z = 0$, in front of the plane $x = 0$ and between the cross plane $y = 0$ and lies to the their parallel plane $y = 5$, calculate the following integral:

$\int_{F}^{} \! a\cdot dn \, = ? $

Idea:
I tried to find normal vector as cross product of partial derivatives and to put that in integral, but I am not getting correct solution and I am not sure what to do whith those planes that are given. Can someone help me with this? Correct solution: $-25$.

Edit: My translation here is not the best, but this example is connected with integral curves and flows.

Comment: Is that the exact wording of the question? Did you translate it?

Comment: No it is not. I translated it from another language. I think this example is connected with Gauss's theorem.